# Verificar se uma variavel existe em uma classe

Tags: java, reflexão

Pessoal estou tentando verificar se uma variável existe em uma classe. Para isso estou usando o código:

```
try{
    clazz.getDeclaredField("id");
} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Com isso eu consigo ver sem problemas.

Meu Problema:
Quando a variável não existe o java imprime no console o nome da variável que não existe, eu preciso que essa informação não apareça caso a variável não exista.
como faço para não fazer isso? algum pode me dar uma luz?

EDIT:
mesmo eu removendo System.out.println(e.getMessage()); ele continua imprimindo o nome da variável que não existe, é isso que eu não quero que apareça

Comment: Se você colocar o print dentro do catch não funciona?

Comment: na verdade é isso que esta acontecendo, o sistema lança no console o print, e eu preciso tirar isso. Talvez tenha ficado um pouco confuso

Comment: Olá. Me parece que o seu problema vai além do trecho de código. O fato de ter mencionado que o Java ainda imprime o algo mesmo depois de removido provavelmente significa que você não está executando a mesma versão do código que está editando. Pode ser que o arquivo compilado esteja defasado, por exemplo, o que ocorre se seu editor não compila ou não está configurado para compilar automaticamente as classe alteradas. Antes de tentar coisas mais avançadas, sugiro que primeiro tente dominar melhor o ambiente em que está desenvolvendo para evitar frustrações e inconsistências como esta no futuro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem certeza que não quer fazer nada se a variável não existir? Isso provavelmente será um erro de programação e deveria ser consertado. Exceção não serve para isto.

Se quiser insistir basta imprimir nada:

```
try {
    clazz.getDeclaredField("id");
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/Swalling.java).

Comment: não, eu só preciso fazer algo se ela existir, meu problema é que o java está imprimindo no console a variável caso ela não exista, e eu não quero que ela imprima, nãop preciso disso, acrescentando, mesmo tirando System.out.println(e.getMessage()); ele esta imprimindo